# How to Handle 2 tables with one form_tag? Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, form-for, fields-for

1. Beneficiaries

   - id (PK)
   - name
   - age
   - income
2. Beneficiary_loans

   - id (PK)
   - beneficiary_id (FK)
   - amount
   - rate
   - period

What I'm doing is, selecting a list of beneficiary from [Beneficiaries] table and displaying as follows

```
<%= form_tag({:action => 'update_survey_list_status', :status=>4}) do %>
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Beneficiary Details</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Rate</th>
      <th>Period</th><th>
      <input type='checkbox' name='checkall' onclick='checkedAll();'>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <% @publishedlist.each do |b| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= b.firstname %></td>
      <%= fields_for :beneficiaryloan do |bloan| %> 
        <td> <%= bloan.text_field :amount%></td>
    <td> <%= bloan.text_field :rate%></td>
    <td> <%= bloan.text_field :period%></td>
      <% end %> 
     <td><%= check_box_tag "benificiary_ids[]",b.id, :name => "benificiary_ids[]"%>     </td>
   </tr>
   <% end %>
  </table> <%= submit_tag "Approve", :class=>'form_buttons'  %>
<% end %>
```

In controller,

```
@beneficiaries=Beneficiary.find(:all, :conditions => ["id IN (?)",     params[:benificiary_ids]])  
@beneficiaries.each do |b|
    @beneficiaryloan = Beneficiaryloan.new(params[:beneficiaryloan])
    @beneficiaryloan.beneficiary_id=b.id
    @beneficiaryloan.hfi_id=session[:id].to_s
    @beneficiaryloan.status_id=params[:status]
    @beneficiaryloan.save
end
```

What I'm not getting is

```
params[:beneficiaryloan]
```

Values are coming as NULL
Am I missing something here in this form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following,

1. With the help of any browser tool(eg:firebug), make sure that the form has been rendered properly. Sometimes due to some misplaced tags(generally happens with table structure) the form does not renders properly.
2. Try to remove the table structure and see if the form works.
3. Make sure your association is fine, i guess it should be Beneficiary has many Beneficiaryloan

If none of the above helps, please post the request parameters over here.

Comment: form is Rendering properly, even other than input field values like **beneficiary_id,hfi_id, status_id** are storing in DB. only input fields are not storing. the amount input filed rendering like this`<input class="forms_txtbx" id="beneficiaryloan_amount" name="beneficiaryloan[amount]" size="30" type="text" />`

Comment: Could you please post the request parameters?

Comment: Parameters: {"commit"=>"Approve", "benificiary_ids"=>["37"], "authenticity_token"=>"zMecG8/dwTs8kb/aeimrmho47J/5SLkS7N6E
YKtKpBQ=", "utf8"=>"Γ£ô", "id"=>"13", "beneficiary"=>{"beneficiaryloan"=>{"period"=>"", "amount"=>"", "rate"=>""}}}

Comment: I smell something wrong with the form, if we have more than one beneficiary, we should be able to get retrieve them in an array of beneficiary loans with may be id as the beneficiary id. Try using something like this <%= fields_for "new_bloan_attributes[#{b.id}]" do |bloan| %> instead of <%= fields_for :beneficiaryloan do |bloan| %>

Comment: Ya i added, and could u please tell me how I should get it in Controller? like Beneficiaryloan.new(params[:new_bloan_attributes]) or something else?

Comment: params[:new_bloan_attributes].each do|k, v| Beneficiary.find(k).beneficiary_loans.build(v).save if Beneficiary.find(k) end

Comment: In controller I used as `    @beneficiaryloan = params[:beneficiaryloan].each do|k, v|
          Beneficiary.find(k).beneficiaryloan.build(v).save
        end` _ and error is coming like this The error occurred while evaluating nil.each _ **and request parametres** "commit"=>"Approve","benificiary_ids"=>"37","38","39"],"authenticity_token"=>"zMecG8/dwTs8kb/aeimrmho47J5SLkS7N6EYKtKpBQ=","utf8"=>"✓","checkall"=>"on",":beneficiaryloan"=>{"37"=>"period"=>"11","amount"=>"1111111","rate"=>"11"}

Comment: It should be pretty easy to do, i have added a demo app to my github repository https://github.com/nithyanandankm/DemoApp. Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Dude one final help, How to assign other attributes while saving benificary_loans? I need to store status_id, project_id etc.. so far input values are inserting into DB.

Comment: Dude one final help, How to assign other attributes while saving benificary_loans? I need to store status_id, project_id etc.. so far input values are inserting into DB.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4500/discussion-between-shreekumar-s-and-nkm)